# Forcing LandScape orientation without using [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationAnyOrientation]

Tags: ios, xcode, orientation, appstore-approval

I have a weird problem I can't figure out how to solve it! 
My app supports any type of orientation (portrait, landscape ect..), but a new section (view) I designed, is useful only in landscape.
So I have to force my new view to be loaded in landscape once I pressed a button or rotate the device orientation when this particular view is created.

Using solve everything but I read on the web that using this API will lead your app to be rejected by Apple.
Is it still true or I can use it?

Having lots of views I used a UIViewController as "container", so I can handle them better. I wounder if using this may be a problem itself...
I tried to rotate the view with a CGTransform and "lock" the rotation using a BOOL inside the view container, this solved the layout problem so the view is displayed correctly but when a textView becomes firsresponder the keyboard is showed in portrait mode.
That's why the device orientation is still portrait.

I also tried to work on the keyboard layout to display it correctly but nothing worked.

Thank you for any help you'll provide me!

Answer (score 16):

Put this code in viewWillAppear

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationCurrentContext];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectZero;
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[viewController release];
```

This will rotate new view controller to device orientation

Comment: Man, you are a damn genius. I was looking for this piece of code for almost two days now. And the solution is so simple. :)
Exactly what I need. 
Thx man. :)

Comment: I am searching for this solution a long time. I am not believed what this is possible, but... =)

Comment: I wish I could promote this answer somehow, because Stack is full of wrong/long answers for this one. Amazing!

Comment: This solution is just great! Could you explain how it works please? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It certainly looks like magic, but I would really appreciate if you could try to explain what's happening underneath. I'm having problems in trying to put the orientation back to what it was after using this technic. Any help?

Comment: I got this error when using this code. The error is : Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for UIViewController